# How to fit big table

Tags: tables

I'm a novice in LaTeX, started just few days ago, but I have to complete report in a few days and I'm asking for help.
This is code for a table:

```
\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{Measurements made by local people}
\label{tab:t1}\
\footnotesize\setlength{\tabcolsep}{5pt}
\begin{tabular}{l@{\hspace{10pt}} *{11}{c}}
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{Regions} & \multirow{2}{*}{Total}& \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{Types of forest canopy} & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Location of forest} & \multirow{2}{*}{Open type in Community Forest} & \multirow{2}{*}{Open type in private forest} & \multirow{2}{*}{Close type in Community forest} & \multirow{2}{*}{Close type in private fores}\\
\cline{3-7}
& &Open&Close&None&Community forest&Private forest& & & & \\
\hline
Chitwan& 183 & 28 & 153 & 2 & 179 & 4 & 27 &  1 &  151 & 2\\
Gorkha& 191 & 33 & 157 & 1 & 185 & 6 & 33 &  0 &  151 & 6\\
\hline
Total&374&61&310&3&364&10& \multicolumn{2}{c}{61} &  \multicolumn{2}{c}{310} \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

But the table does not fit the page and I don't know what to do. I need this table on one page fitted by width like here:

[image]

Comment: welcome to tex.sx, but please always provide a complete document including `\documentclass` and ending `\end{document}` It's hard to suggest ways of making something fit if we don't know the size of the thing it's fitting in to:-) probably `\multcolumn{1}{p{2cm}}{Community forest}` to allow line breaking in the heading  is what you are looking for

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I see several possibilities

- **Restructure** your table. You could change column to rows (transpose), or you could combine some columns.
- Define **columns with fixed width** by using `p{<width>}`; this will force linebreaking. You can also use manual line breaks in the table header.
- Or **reduce the font size** in your tabular, by using

  ```
  {\small
  \begin{tabular}...
  \end{tabular}
  }
  ```

  Available font sizes are `\tiny`, `\scriptsize`, `\footnotesize`, `\small`, `\normalsize`, `\large`, `\Large`, `\LARGE`, `\huge`, `\Huge`
- Or you **scale** the whole table to the size needed.

  ```
  \scalebox{0.7}{ \begin{tabular}... \end{tabular} }
  ```

  or with the `\resizebox` command
- use a **landscape page** for your table, by using `sidewaystable` from the package `rotating`.

Hope that helps.

Comment: +1 for transpose -- if this is actually the whole table (which it may well be as it adds up) -- if this is 2 rows from a bigger table for clarity that's a different matter, and landscape might be a better option.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: You can use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863) as I did in my edit.

Comment: Resizing a table is considered bad practise.